# 3rd Party Hipchat Integration

Tags: chat

At my company we use Hipchat and I really dislike the UX and would much prefer to use Slack's UX.

Is there a way I can integrate Slack (or a similar client) with Hipchat so I can communicate in my Hipchat rooms without having to use Hipchat?